# Open PDF from server in a browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer, pdf

Hi I've got follow json:

```
let help = {
    url: 'file://myServer/folder1/myFile.pdf'
};
```

With this function I try to open the file in a browser:

```
openPdf() {
    window.open(help.url);
}
```

This is my html:

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.openPdf()">Open PDF</button>
```

Now, when I click on the button, a new tab opens in the browser without the pdf file. There isn't also my url from the json. It opens a empty page - `about:blank`. But when I copy the url from the json and paste it again in the browser, it opens the file correctly. But this also works only, when I put `file://` before the url (without this, or with `http://` etc. it also doesn't work) - **Browser** = `Google Chrome`. The confusing thing is: It works on `Internet Explorer`! When I open the url (with `file://`), than it shows me the pdf in a new browser tab. Is there perhaps a pdf plugin for browser, that isn't installed on chrome? Any ideas what could be wrong here? Thanks

Comment: What if you pass a relative path instead? `\folder1\myFile.pdf'`?

Comment: Hi @HanletEscaño the pdf is on another server than my web-application... I have to use the whole link to open it from there...

Comment: Is is on a shared filesystem (file://)? I think you are hitting some security feature about opening  files on local/shared filesystems. Does it work with http?

Comment: Hi @GiorgioBozio Like I wrote in the question, it doesn't work with http:// or https://...

Comment: Well, `file://` won't work. You need the HTTP protocol version of that path, not the FILE protocol one. `http://servername/folder1/myFile.pdf`.

Comment: @HanletEscaño but when I use http:// it don't work. How can I get the http protocol? Is there perhaps a security feature from the server that doesn't allowe me to open the pdf?

Comment: Ok, have you tried serving the file programmatically and add the relevant http headers, like content-type and Content-Disposition?

Comment: What's on the server backend?

Comment: @GiorgioBozio Oh, I can't really give you an answer, I'm just working on the frontend I have no idea what's going on on the database or the backend... I can't give you a good answer, sorry :/... but have you an idea, why the browser can open the pdf (with file://), when I paste it into the adress and when I try to open the same URl with window.open it can't handle it?

Comment: @GiorgioBozio I can't believe it, it works in IE with file:// in the url.......Why???

Comment: @HanletEscaño Look at my comment below (IE)......

Comment: I think there is a pdf plugin for browser, that is installed on IE but perhaps not on google chrome, where it doesn't work.....